# Make sure that browser opened by webdriver is always in focus

Tags: selenium, webdriver

If the browser window is not in focus, all webdriver identifications on the current page fail.

How can the browser be brought into focus, using webdriver?

Comment: What browser? Firefox, IE, Chrome?

Comment: Why wouldn't the instance have focus? If you're trying to operate normally on the computer running the tests, then yeah, that won't work well since Selenium uses OS native keyboard and click instructions that you would interfere with. Sometimes, [`driver.switchTo().defaultContent()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.TargetLocator.html#defaultContent%28%29) (and/or `switchTo().activeElement()`) helps - mostly on IE. What's your use case?

Comment: The process launching the browser is sometimes retaining focus - this appears to interfere with the browser not rendering because it idles invisible tabs by design if another window covers the entire browser tab.

Answer (score 9):

`executeScript("window.focus();")` **didn't work for me in the latest Chrome** (v47 at the time of this post)

However I found a hack in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19167961/1082449) which *does* work in this version of Chrome.

Here are the generic steps, since the question doesn't specify the Selenium API language:

1. Show alert by executing script in browser
2. Accept the alert

Implementation in `webdriverjs`, which I'm using

```
const chrome = setupChromeWebdriver(); // get your webdriver here

chrome.executeScript('alert("Focus window")'))
  .then(() => chrome.switchTo().alert().accept());
```

Answer (score 6):

```
((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("window.focus();");
```

should do the trick!

Comment: +1. So simple.  Saves me writing a very convoluted AHK script.

Comment: I am using internet explorer 9. Doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me. After the code that opens the browser, issue this snippet:

```
String window = driver.getWindowHandle();
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("alert('Test')");
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
driver.switchTo().window(window);
```

Comment: Had no effect using this combined strategy of both methods on Chrome v 87.0
(Windows on a Selenium grid to a local browser)

Answer (score 1):

Selenium 3.0 takes this:

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)po.WebDriver).ExecuteScript("window.focus();");
```

Comment: This doesn't mean browser window will get actual focus, i.e. it doesn't guarantee browser window will be active on OS level; there are cases where this will only trigger OS level `attention` message.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the focus at the "driver options" should work:

```
InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
options.setCapability("requireWindowFocus", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (in python):

```
driver.minimize_window()
driver.maximize_window()
```