# Bring the Firefox Browser to Front using selenium Java (Mac OSX)

Tags: java, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I am using three instances of fire fox driver for automation.I need to bring current active firefox browser into front, Because I am using some robo classes for some opertation. I had tried java script alert for google chrome in mac ( same operation) and its worked fine. In windows used user32 lib. In the case of firefox mac its showing the alert in background but the web page is not come into front.

```
((JavascriptExecutor)this.webDriver).executeScript("alert('Test')");
this.webDriver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

The above code I used for chrome in Mac. Same code is working and showing alert for firefox but the window is not coming to front.

Please suggest if there any other method for doing the same in firefox.

Comment: thank you! I has this exact same question *for* chrome! The firefox answer below doesn't seem to work, executing `window.focus()` doesn't seem to work, but your trick of showing an alert then accepting it does work. Incredibly useful!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Store the window handle first in a variable, and then use it to go back to the window later on.

```
//Store the current window handle
String currentWindowHandle = this.webDriver.getWindowHandle();

//run your javascript and alert code
((JavascriptExecutor)this.webDriver).executeScript("alert('Test')"); 
this.webDriver.switchTo().alert().accept();

//Switch back to to the window using the handle saved earlier
this.webDriver.switchTo().window(currentWindowHandle);
```

Additionally, you can try to maximise the window after switching to it, which should also activate it.

```
this.webDriver.manage().window().maximize();
```

Comment: This is actually an awesome work around, recently helped me a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try switching using the window name:

```java
driver.switchTo().window("windowName");
```

Alternatively, you can pass a "window handle" to the `switchTo().window()` method. Knowing this, it’s possible to iterate over every open window like so:

```
for (String handle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
  driver.switchTo().window(handle);
}
```

Based on the Selenium documentation: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But I found that also not working, I have already tried switch to window

Answer (score 0):

As described in other topics, you can use

```
 driver.manage().window().setPosition(new Point(-2000, 0));
```

too.

Answer (score 0):

```python
# notifications for selenium
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
current_path = os.getcwd()  # current working path
chrome_path = os.path.join(current_path, 'chromedriver')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path, chrome_options=chrome_options)
browser.switch_to.window(browser.current_window_handle)
browser.implicitly_wait(30)
browser.maximize_window()
browser.get("http://facebook.com")
```

Answer (score 0):

Only thing that worked for me on mac: `self.driver.fullscreen_window()`.