# How to open chrome driver (Using Selenium Webdriver) in foreground. By default its opening in background with no focus

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

I've been using chrome driver (with selenium wedriver), so far it never caused any issue, now for some requirement it has to be in foreground with focus on it.
How can I make sure it is in the foreground?

Comment: I am using `wmctrl` for that. Open your webbrowser to some local HTML file with unique unique name, find the browser with `wmctrl` using that name and get it where you want (focus, position, desktop). Redirect the browser to the real page you want and delete the temporary file with unique name

Comment: I tried wmctrl in mac but doesn't seem to work there. What I need to do use this in mac.

Comment: I am not sure. If the Mac's window manager is EWMH compliant this should work. If Apple has re-invented the wheel once more `wmctrl` will not work. I am not familiar with Mac to suggest something Mac specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the answer from one of the post, it worked for me, URL:

[Bring the Firefox Browser to Front using selenium Java (Mac OSX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19167961/bring-the-firefox-browser-to-front-using-selenium-java-mac-osx)

Answer (score 2):

Just immediately after navigating to your test URL, Maximize and Switch To the new window. It will come in the fore ground (provided you don't interfere with your mouse ;)

```
    browser.navigate().to(test_URL);
    browser.manage().window().maximize();
    browser.switchTo().window(browser.getWindowHandle());
```

Comment: I am sorry. it doesn't work. Chrome still opens in background with no focus. Any other suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: If on Mac, try this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19167961/bring-the-firefox-browser-to-front-using-selenium-java-mac-osx

Comment: This one works well !! This is kind of a hook, may not work on security compliant browsers but it works for me.. Thanks a lot.