# Bring the IE Browser to Front/focus

Tags: java, selenium, internet-explorer, awtrobot

I am testing a platform with Selenium and IE 11 Using IE Driver 3.0.0.

- Windows 10 Pro
- Java JDK 1.8.0_25

As for my research, I tried this:

```
String currentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
driver.switchTo().window(currentWindow);
```

And with JavaScript, I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19167961/bring-the-firefox-browser-to-front-using-selenium-java-mac-osx). (See first answer)

Is there any way I can bring the IE window that selenium opens and bring it to front/focus it? Since I use a robot at one point to perform a few actions, I need the browser to be on focus automatically, otherwise my robot actions are not effective.

Answer (score 0):

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.focus()");
```