# How to set Firefox to start in the foreground using Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, mozilla, geckodriver

I'm using geckodriver 0.19.0 with Selenium server standalone 3.6 and Java8.
Both Firefox 56.0.2 (64-bit) and  57.0b13 (dev edition) start behind other windows on the active PC screen (the screen that is being selected).

This is not the case for Chrome or Chromium, which always start on the foreground.

Is there any Firefox command-line option that would force the browser to start in the foreground?
I tried to look [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config_entries#Browser.) but didn't find an appropriate option. A "desired capability" for it is missing too.

Comment: The answer seems to be for chrome but you can give it a shot - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649637/make-sure-that-browser-opened-by-webdriver-is-always-in-focus

Comment: The command line option is [-foreground](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options#-foreground) . The link you posted is for firefox profile options

Comment: For some reason that option is not found in the firefox -h in terminal.
The command options.addArguments("-foreground"); doesn't take any effect in selenium

Comment: It seems the same issue with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19167961/bring-the-firefox-browser-to-front-using-selenium-java-mac-osx). Please add `Java` tag in order this question to be found by more people.