# Foreground Firefox browser using selenium python (Mac OSX)

Tags: python-3.x, macos, selenium

I'm running selenium tests with python in terminal. When I run the test, the Firefox window opens behind the terminal. How do I get it to open the Firefox window in the foreground?

I've tried:

```
# Store the current window handle
currentWindowHandle = webDriver.current_window_handle

# Run your javascript alert code
webDriver.execute_script("alert('Test')")
webDriver.switch_to.alert.accept()

# Switch back to to the window using the handle saved earlier
webDriver.switch_to.window(currentWindowHandle)
```

As well as:

```
webDriver.maximize_window()
```

These two solutions were proposed from [this previous stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19167961/bring-the-firefox-browser-to-front-using-selenium-java-mac-osx). They do not work for osx though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A work around I found is to use the fullscreen_window method. This forces the window to the front as fullscreen and then right after I set the window size to what I want.

This works for me on High Sierra:

```
webDriver.fullscreen_window() # Bring firefox window to foreground
webDriver.set_window_size(1200,900) # Change size back to desktop size
```

[selenium python docs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver)

Answer (score 0):

To get this working you can use the `args` key of the `moz:firefoxOptions` capability and specify `-foreground`. This forces Firefox to open in the foreground.

For the Selenium Python bindings it will look like:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

opts = Options()
opts.add_argument("-foreground")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=opts)
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I got this to work on macOS Mojave is as code bellow :

```
import os
os.environ['MOZ_HEADLESS'] = '1'
```

and

```
os.environ['MOZ_HEADLESS'] = ''
```

to revert