# C# Selenium check if browser is active/focus

Tags: c#, selenium

i need to send some key inputs to different browser sessions and want to make sure the right session is active.

i used this method, which is actually working.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

[DllImport("User32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

driver = new ChromeDriver()
IntPtr browserWriteTarget1 = GetForegroundWindow();
driver = new ChromeDriver()
IntPtr browserWriteTarget2 = GetForegroundWindow();
driver = new ChromeDriver()
IntPtr browserWriteTarget3 = GetForegroundWindow();

SetForegroundWindow(browserWriteTarget1);

if (browserWriteTarget1 == GetForegroundWindow()
                {
                    SendKeys.SendWait($"{myKey}");
                    Thread.Sleep(tWait);
                }
```

The problem is if the user clicks around, while `driver = new ChromeDriver` is loading, that `IntPtr browserWriteTarget = GetForegroundWindow();` will get the wrong value and the process will break.

The browser titles are all the same as im opening the same URL several times.

Is there a better solution, to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

### Approach 1: Add a IJavascriptExecutor script

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("window.focus();");
```

By calling this statement in combination with the specific driver instance will give the newly opened chrome browser the focus.

### Approach 2: Save a CurrentWindowHandle

```
        driver = new ChromeDriver(@"D:/Projects/Training/SeleniumApp/SeleniumApp/");
        string driverWindowHandle = driver.CurrentWindowHandle;

        driver_2 = new ChromeDriver(@"D:/Projects/Training/SeleniumApp/SeleniumApp/");
        string driver_2_WindowHandle = driver_2.CurrentWindowHandle;

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com/");

        driver_2.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.bing.com/");

        driver.SwitchTo().Window(driverWindowHandle);
```

This method saves a handle of the window that's been opened through a specific driver instance. With this handle you can perform browser actions on a single browser. Use the code to see how this works and you'll find that clicking around will not influence the code's performance.

### Sources

1. [Make sure that browser opened by webdriver is always in focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649637/make-sure-that-browser-opened-by-webdriver-is-always-in-focus);
2. [Bring the Firefox Browser to Front using selenium Java (Mac OSX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19167961/bring-the-firefox-browser-to-front-using-selenium-java-mac-osx);

Comment: My problem is to get the window hwnd correctly. Once the hwnd is right, I can just call the windows by `SetForegroundWindow()`

Comment: @RobertoPagnotta See approach 2

Comment: To set the handle correctly works perfectly fine with this solution. I had initially a similar code using `driver.CurrentWindowHandle` but i got stuck at the if statement, to ensure the driver window has focus before sending a key.

Comment: If focus = yes, send key, else messagebox.show("focus lost").

Answer (score 0):

Get current running Processes and keep track of what is being added. And then you can just use that Handle without bothering what is actually showing on the Foreground.

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
...
// First Get current running processes. Filter them by the ProcessName.
var myProcesses = Process.GetProcesses()
   .Where(p => p.ProcessName.Equals("MyProcess", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
   .ToList();

// Launch Chrome
driver = new ChromeDriver();

// You might want to add some wait, and confirm if the Processes are increasing before
// for ex:
while(Process.GetProcesses()
   .Where(p => p.ProcessName.Equals("MyProcess", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
   .Count() == myProcesses.Count + 1)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000); // wait a second
    // you may also put some timeout, so we are not in this loop forever, in case of some error.
}  

// Get Current running process again.
var newProcesses = Process.GetProcesses()
   .Where(p => p.ProcessName.Equals("MyProcess", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
   .ToList();

foreach(var process in myProcesses)
{
    // Remove the old processes.
    newProcesses.Remove(process);
}

// Get the Handle of the only remaining process
IntPtr browserWriteTarget1 = processes.First().Handle;

// repeat to the next one
```

Comment: This solution is trowing an error CS0019 Operator cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'int', on `myProcesses.Count + 1)`

Comment: myProcesses was an array, so it does not have Count property, instead you should use Length. Otherwise, you can also change myProcesses to be a List instead of Array, so you can access the Count property

Comment: Both solutions do not work.  `while (Process.GetProcesses() 
               .Where(p => p.ProcessName.Equals("MyProcess", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))  
               .Count == myProcesses.Count + 1)`   Operator '==' cannot be applied to operants of type method group and int

Comment: `Process.GetProcesses() .Where(p => p.ProcessName.Equals("MyProcess", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))` is an `IEnumerable`, so you would need to use Linq's `Count()` extension.

Comment: the name processes does not exist in the current context   `IntPtr browserWriteTarget1 = processes.First().Handle;`