# Javascript - How to get your browser in focus

Tags: javascript

I'm running a script on a retail site that when the browser is in focus, it passes every time. When the browser is not in focus, it fails every time.

My waitUntil(Waits.elementDisplayed(....  doesn't work when not in focus.

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649637/how-to-make-sure-that-browser-opened-by-webdriver-is-always-in-focus.

Answer (score 0):

you can detect if the browser is out of focus with the following javascript function

```
function onBlur() {
    document.body.className = 'blurred';
};
function onFocus(){
    document.body.className = 'focused';
};

if (/*@cc_on!@*/false) { // check for Internet Explorer
    document.onfocusin = onFocus;
    document.onfocusout = onBlur;
} else {
    window.onfocus = onFocus;
    window.onblur = onBlur;
}
```

[Reference](http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/detect-browser-window-focus)

However, i'm not sure if you always getFocus if it is out of focus. Hope this helps.

Comment: there is a DOM focus method also http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_focus.asp