# ChromeDriver does not open a window yet test is still successful

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to run a webdriver test in python on a mac (El Capitan 10.11.5).
I was successful running the same test with FirefoxDriver (using FF 46, before marionette).
When I try doing the same using chromedriver 2.22 or 2.20, I get a strange result - the test runs and passes, but I see no window doing it.

I'm not trying to run a headless browser - I *want* to see the browser.

Any ideas what's going on here?

I'm using python 2.7.11, selenium 2.53.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser is actually opened but *it is not brought into front/focus*.

There are [several workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649637/make-sure-that-browser-opened-by-webdriver-is-always-in-focus), like executing `window.focus()`, but I prefer firing up an `alert()` and immediately accepting it:

```
driver.execute_script('alert("Focus window");'))
drivere.switch_to.alert.accept()
```

Comment: Simple and direct. Thanks!