# How do I refocus Selenium Webdriver C# to a window after using an AutoIT process?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, focus, autoit-c#-wrapper

I have used AutoIt to deal with an authentication popup that Selenium Webdriver was unable to send keys to.
Now, after the AutoIT process, I can successfully log into the website but none of the code after the process appears to work.
I think that the window may no longer be the focus of Selenium Webdriver.

Is there a way to get the window's handle/name before the authentication popup occurs and then use that after the process to refocus on the window?

Below is my current code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System.Linq;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;


namespace Selenium
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        static IWebDriver driverGC;

        public object ExpectedConditions { get; private set; }

        [AssemblyInitialize]
        public static void SetUp(TestContext context)
        {
            driverGC = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Browser Drivers\Chrome");

        }
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestGC()
        {
            string UserNameGC = "username@website";

            try
            {

                driverGC.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://WEBSITE.com/");
                **string parentWindow = driverGC.CurrentWindowHandle.ToString();**

                driverGC.FindElement(By.Id("i0116")).SendKeys(UserNameGC);
                driverGC.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
                driverGC.FindElement(By.Id("idSIButton9")).Click();

                Thread.Sleep(3000);

                Process.Start(@"C:\AutoIT.exe");

                Thread.Sleep(6000);

                driverGC.SwitchTo().Window(parentWindow);
                driverGC.FindElement(By.Id("search-reviewee")).SendKeys("John Smith");
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
                driverGC.FindElement(By.Id("searchbtn")).Click();




            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

            finally
            {
                driverGC.Dispose();
                driverGC.Quit();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to use **string parentWindow = driverGC.CurrentWindowHandle.ToString()** to get the handle and then (after the process) **driverGC.SwitchTo().Window(parentWindow);** to return to the window.

EDIT: I am using Chrome Version 78.0.3904.108.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have also tried following the advice from https://stackoverflow.com/a/34426453/12363556 to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

To bring back the [Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) focus back to the window after using an AutoIT process you can use the following command:

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("window.focus();");
```