# Selenium: How to check that current window (handle) is in focus?

Tags: javascript, selenium, web-scraping, window

My problem is that I want to crawl a very modern, dynamic web page. I noticed that some elements are not just dynamically loaded, they are only loaded when the window is in focus (foreground)!

How can I check with the Selenium API that a web driver window is 'in focus'?

Comment: Did my solution resolved your problem?

Comment: Sadly not, but still thanks. I am trying out many alternatives to make it work the way intended..

Comment: OK, no problems

Answer (score 1):

This command is making to be the driver window in focus:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("window.focus();");
```

It works in most cases.
However sometimes you will need to use another techniques.
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649637/make-sure-that-browser-opened-by-webdriver-is-always-in-focus) for more details.